# Using an environment inside an environment

Tags: environments

I am often declaring environments which use other environment:

```
\newenvironment{foo}%
{\begin{itemize}}%
{\end{itemize}}
```

Somebody told me it is better to use the *internal* macros for the inner environment.

```
\newenvironment{foo}%
{\itemize}%
{\enditemize}
```

Is it true? If so, why is it better?

Best regards,

Luc.

Comment: @Mico There are cases where the environment form won't work e.g. if the environment is defined with `environ`. So `prooftrees` needs to use `\forest ... \endforest` as `\begin{forest} ... \end{forest}` won't work. But I agree that in standard cases, it is hard to think of a reason to prefer the macro version.

Comment: @cfr - Thanks for providing an example of when the embedded macros version works whereas the embedded environment version does not.

Answer (score 10):

Using the internal forms allows for better error checking. Suppose you have

```
\newenvironment{fooA}
  {\begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}

\newenvironment{fooB}
  {\itemize}
  {\enditemize}
```

If you forget `\end{fooA}` you'll receive a message about

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{itemize} on input line 13 ended by \end{document}.
```

but if you forget `\end{fooB}` the message will be

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{fooB} on input line 13 ended by \end{document}.
```

In some cases, the internal form is mandatory, for instance when defining new verbatim environments with the `verbatim` package or when using environments defined with `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package. Another important case is when you define new environments on top of the `amsmath` display ones.

In some cases, however, the internal form is to be avoided, the main one being `lrbox`: using `\lrbox` and `\endlrbox` is always wrong.

Comment: Wow, half a million rep, that's really something, thanks for all that you contribute here

Comment: In just a few hours (or minutes?!) you'll have passed the 500K reputation threshold on this site. Congratulations in advance, and many thanks for all the good stuff I've learned from you over the past few years!!

Comment: My best congratulations, Enrico!!! Now you're a myth!!!